# pandas dataframe .loc or .ix inplace slice modification not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

```
indexes_to_correct = simbolo.index.date <= effective_date
simbolo.loc[indexes_to_correct, [const.OpenPriceCol, const.ClosePriceCol, const.HighPriceCol,
                                                 const.LowPriceCol]] *= ratio
```

simbolo is a (yahoo finance) dataframe consisting of several columns and indexes_to_correct returns a boolean ndarray which I use for index slicing, list of columns is label slicing and I modify inplace the values by multiplying by ratio(float64)

This seems to work randomly with some dataframes and others not. I've debugged this code and indexes_to_correct boolean array looks ok, also columns are present in the array and if I force the change by evaluating in the debugger the line of code it works, but in practice in the interpreter it won't.

I'm actually using python 2.7.12 (anaconda bundle) with pandas 0.19.1 (tried downgrading 1 or 2 versions with same result). I have no clue what's happening here.... Might this be a bug?

Comment: What are all the `const.<name>` columns? Column names should be quoted.

Comment: They are. See:
`
class const:
        DateCol = 'Date'
        OpenPriceCol = 'Open'
        HighPriceCol = 'High'
        LowPriceCol = 'Low'
        ClosePriceCol = 'Close'
        VolumeCol = 'Volume'
        AdjustedCloseCol='Adj Close'
        ...
`

Comment: This worked for me

`from pandas_datareader import data
df = data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start='2014-01-01')
effective_date = '2014-05-01'
indexes_to_correct = df.index <= effective_date
ratio = 51.1
df.loc[indexes_to_correct, [const.OpenPriceCol, const.ClosePriceCol, const.HighPriceCol, const.LowPriceCol]] *= ratio
df`

Comment: You're all right. Problem for me was that input data from yahoo finance was incorrect. Thanks!